# Tkinter : How to set a background color to a cell of a grid?

Tags: tkinter, colors, background, grid, cell

I have created a Tkinter grid and would like to set different background colors for different cells of the grid.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: How are you creating the grid? Tkinter doesn't have a "grid" object, only a method named `grid`.

Answer (score 1):

I create the grid like this :

```
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *

M = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

root = Tk()

for i in range(len(M)): #Rows
    for j in range(len(M[0])): #Columns
        b = Label(root, text=str(M[i][j]))
        b.grid(row=i, column=j)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem recently! I think you need to give a few more details but here's a general answer and what worked for me:

- Store your cells as values in a dictionary with it's (row, column) tuples as keys!
- Now you can reference these cells with their tuples and change their attributes (Example below)

(Example) Let's say you're defining your widgets within two for loops like so:

```
    widgets_dictionary = {} # initialize your empty dictionary

    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(columns):

            # widget definition here, let's say it's a label
            label = Label(...)
            label.pack()

            # create a reference to the widget in your dictionary
            widget[(i,j)] = label

    # Now, referring to your specific question:
    # (x,y) = the index of the cell you want to change
    # colour = the background colour you want to change it to

    widget[(x,y)].config(bg = "colour")
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```py
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *

M = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5,6],[7,8,9]])
colors = [["red","gold","yellow"], ["cyan","green","brown"],["azure",'skyblue','lightgreen']]
root = Tk()


root.geometry("500x500")
root.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(2,weight=1)

root.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(2,weight=1)


for i in range(len(M)): #Rows
    for j in range(len(M[0])): #Columns
        b = Label(root, text=str(M[i][j]),background=colors[i][j])
        b.grid(row=i, column=j,sticky="sewn")

mainloop()
```